# Why is Thunderbird randomly moving IMAP messages to the trash?

Tags: thunderbird, ubuntu-10.04

I have 4 IMAP email accounts set up in Thunderbird 3.0.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.01 LTS. These are all accounts on a server which I administer. On one particular account, seemingly randomly, thunderbird will move certain recent emails to the trash. Without being asked to. Often without me even using the computer! I run thunderbird on my laptop and while working off my desktop (which sits next to the leptop) I will suddenly see a bunch of emails dissappear from my inbox, only to find them in the Trash.

When it happens (and I know it just happened), `undo` will restore the emails. Problem is, I just looked through my trash to find at least a dozen emails in there from yesterday which I had not realized were in the trash. So using `undo` is not a reliable enough solution.

This *seems* to happen only on one account even though three of the accounts are on the same server. I'm not positive of that though.

I am at a complete loss as to how to troubleshoot this. I am the only one checking email on these accounts and am not using any other email clients. Ideas?

Comment: Damn, this just happened today and all the messages in my inbox since July 16th just got moved to the trash, intermixed with the messages I did want trashed. What a nightmare. I think I'm going to delete my email account off the server and off of Thunderbird and re-create it.

Comment: I've had it. I switched to Evolution.